# Docker Image Installation fails: "executor failed running [/bin/sh -c docker-php-ext-install ctype exif gd iconv simplexml zip] [...]

Tags: php, docker, installation, makefile, iconv

Hello stackOverflow Community,

i have some issue with installing a existing dockerfile.
I have Docker Version 4.9.0 (80466) and also with the new Version: 4.11.
I am Using WSL2 on a Windows 10 System.

I got these error:

```
    executor failed running [/bin/sh -c docker-php-ext-install ctype exif gd iconv simplexml zip]: exit code: 2
make: *** [Makefile:35: build] Error 1
```

i think here is some important stuff fromt the installing process:

```
    #5 48.54 mkdir .libs
#5 48.55  cc -I/usr/include -DZEND_ENABLE_STATIC_TSRMLS_CACHE=1 -I. -I/usr/src/php/ext/iconv -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/usr/src/php/ext/iconv/include -I/usr/src/php/ext/iconv/main -I/usr/src/php/ext/iconv -I/usr/local/include/php -I/usr/local/include/php/main -I/usr/local/include/php/TSRM -I/usr/local/include/php/Zend -I/usr/local/include/php/ext -I/usr/local/include/php/ext/date/lib -fstack-protector-strong -fpic -fpie -O2 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I/usr/include -fstack-protector-strong -fpic -fpie -O2 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -c /usr/src/php/ext/iconv/iconv.c  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/iconv.o
#5 48.56 In file included from /usr/local/include/php/Zend/zend_config.h:1,
#5 48.56                  from /usr/local/include/php/Zend/zend_portability.h:43,
#5 48.56                  from /usr/local/include/php/Zend/zend_types.h:25,
#5 48.56                  from /usr/local/include/php/Zend/zend.h:27,
#5 48.56                  from /usr/local/include/php/main/php.h:33,
#5 48.56                  from /usr/src/php/ext/iconv/iconv.c:25:
#5 48.56 /usr/local/include/php/main/../main/php_config.h:1976: warning: "ICONV_BROKEN_IGNORE" redefined
#5 48.56  1976 | #define ICONV_BROKEN_IGNORE 0
#5 48.56       |
#5 48.56 In file included from /usr/src/php/ext/iconv/iconv.c:22:
#5 48.56 /usr/src/php/ext/iconv/config.h:59: note: this is the location of the previous definition
#5 48.56    59 | #define ICONV_BROKEN_IGNORE 1
#5 48.56       |
#5 48.71 /usr/src/php/ext/iconv/iconv.c: In function 'zm_startup_miconv':
#5 48.71 /usr/src/php/ext/iconv/iconv.c:284:25: error: '_libiconv_version' undeclared (first use in this function)
#5 48.71   284 |                         _libiconv_version >> 8, _libiconv_version & 0xff);
#5 48.71       |                         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
#5 48.71 /usr/src/php/ext/iconv/iconv.c:284:25: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
#5 48.72 /usr/src/php/ext/iconv/iconv.c: In function '_php_iconv_appendl':
#5 48.72 /usr/src/php/ext/iconv/iconv.c:181:15: warning: implicit declaration of function 'libiconv'; did you mean 'iconv'? [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
#5 48.72   181 | #define iconv libiconv
#5 48.72       |               ^~~~~~~~
#5 48.72 /usr/src/php/ext/iconv/iconv.c:453:29: note: in expansion of macro 'iconv'
#5 48.72   453 |                         if (iconv(cd, (char **)&in_p, &in_left, (char **) &out_p, &out_left) == (size_t)-1) {
#5 48.72       |                             ^~~~~
#5 48.76 make: *** [Makefile:192: iconv.lo] Error 1
------
executor failed running [/bin/sh -c docker-php-ext-install ctype exif gd iconv simplexml zip]: exit code: 2
make: *** [Makefile:35: build] Error 1
```

this is the content from the Dockerfile:

```
    ARG PHP_VERSION=7.4

FROM php:${PHP_VERSION}-cli-alpine AS betl
RUN apk add --no-cache \
        zip \
        zlib-dev \
        openssh \
        rsync \
        freetype-dev \
        libjpeg-turbo-dev \
        libpng-dev \
        libxml2-dev \
        libzip-dev \
        git \
    ;

#Test: delet iconv im next line
RUN docker-php-ext-install ctype exif gd iconv simplexml zip 
#Test: new from Rollexpert 20 and 21:
#Test:  RUN apk add --no-cache --repository http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.13/community/ gnu-libiconv=1.15-r3
#Test: ENV LD_PRELOAD /usr/lib/preloadable_libiconv.so php

RUN apk add --no-cache libssh2-dev autoconf build-base
RUN pecl install ssh2-1.3.1 && docker-php-ext-enable ssh2
RUN apk add jpeg-dev libpng-dev \
    && docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-jpeg \
    && docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) gd

ENV COMPOSER_HOME /composer
ENV COMPOSER_ALLOW_SUPERUSER 1
ENV PATH /composer/vendor/bin:$PATH
ENV PHP_CONF_DIR=/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d

COPY --from=composer:latest /usr/bin/composer /usr/bin/composer

RUN echo "memory_limit=-1" > $PHP_CONF_DIR/99_memory-limit.ini

WORKDIR /betl

ENTRYPOINT ["sh", "./bin/lconsole"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Extensions: `ctype`, `iconv`, `simplexml` are already included in standard php:8-fpm-alpine image, so you should't install them.
Just delete their names from your `RUN docker-php-ext-install ...` line and you'll be OK.

For reference:

```
$ docker run php:8-fpm-alpine php -m        
[PHP Modules]
Core
ctype
curl
date
dom
fileinfo
filter
ftp
hash
iconv
json
libxml
mbstring
mysqlnd
openssl
pcre
PDO
pdo_sqlite
Phar
posix
random
readline
Reflection
session
SimpleXML
sodium
SPL
sqlite3
standard
tokenizer
xml
xmlreader
xmlwriter
zlib

[Zend Modules]
```